# Difference between expressions regarding continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}\times \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R^n}$ be an arbitrary function, e.g., with $n=1$, $f(t,x) = t^2+x.$

What is the difference among the following expressions:

"$f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}\times \mathbb{R}^n$"

"$f(t, \cdot)$ is continuous for each fixed $t$"

"$f$ is continuous in its second argument $x$"

Of course, the literal meaning of both expressions is obvious. However, my questions is how are they (or aren't they) related?

Comment: The first one implies the second one, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To further Git Gud's comment.

The first is often called joint continuity. The second is continuity in the first component.

Even if both $f(\cdot, t)$ and $f(x,\cdot)$ are continuous, joint continuity is not necessarily true, but joint continuity implies component wise continuity.

See here for an example:

[Does factor-wise continuity imply continuity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256906/does-factor-wise-continuity-imply-continuity)

The answer for this post illustrates this point.

Edit: your second and third line means the same thing.

Comment: I'm hereby threatning to remove my up vote until you fix my screen name, (not really, the vote is locked).

Comment: @GitGud so why is this like GitGud when i tag you?

Comment: Sometimes tagging removes spaces between names, that's not what I was referring to though, my name ends with a $d\, \ddot \smile$.

Comment: @GitGud lol, sorry...

Comment: No problem at all.